# Check exponential smoothing forecasts for significant changes

Tags: forecasting, change-point, exponential-smoothing

Suppose I have a time series that I model with double exponential smoothing as implemented in the R package `forecast` via the `ets` function.

The formulas given for double exponential smoothing, i.e.,

$$ 
a_t = \alpha x_t + (1-\alpha) (a_{t-1} + b_{t-1})
$$
$$
b_t = \beta (a_t - a_{t-1}) +(1-\beta)b_{t-1}
$$

illustrate that the constant and the trend parameter can change over time.

I would like to analyse that change of the trend parameter over time, i.e., I want to analyse **whether an observed change in the trend or in the level is statistically significant or not** (as opposed to resulting from random disturbances given the variance of the parameters in the overall time series); or, **at what point in time there is a significant change in the trend or the level parameters**.

Note that this change may occur over the course of  a few obervations and is not necessarily instantaneous.

At first, I thought that the correct way to do that was *structural break analysis*, i.e., to test whether segments of the time series are best described by different models. But I have found out that most structural break analysis literature deals with linear models such as ARIMA instead of exponential smoothing models. While those are, to some degree, equivalent, there are substantial differences between them. I found it quite puzzling that the huge host of structural break packages does not offer a way to analyse `ets` models.

But perhaps this is not relevant here, as before as well as after the possible break point, the time series is assumed to be described by the same double exponential smoothing model, so there is no break point in the sense of a different model explaining the data, but rather a non-random sequence of observational errors that accumulate to changes in $a$ and $b$ respectively.

Here we have to note that the observations are linked to the double exponential smoothing formulas above by
$$ X_t = a + b t + \epsilon $$
where the parameters of the model may change over time, and with $\epsilon$ normally distributed.

So perhaps, instead of analysing break points, should I analyse statistical properties of the observational error term?

And if so, what methods should I use to do that?